# Binaural recording

Tags: binaural

How do I record a binaural recording for my psychoacustic assignment. I have to do 3 for a recording.**strong text**
You can send mme an email to jean.wilkie@student.sit.ac.nz.
I have to do the assignment in next 4 weeks.

Comment: hmmm…a down vote, really?  (frown)

Comment: @Jay Yeah - a bit of a cold welcome, eh? Though you may think it was me who down voted, t'was not. I pointed him in the right direction to go, though. ;-) 

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SSD.

Please do a search before asking a question which has been answered already. I found these in less than 3 seconds that will most likely be helpful to you.

[Binaural Recordings](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/5757/binaural-recordings)

[Binaural Dummy Head [DIY]](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/binaural-dummy-head-diy)

[How do binaural recordings sound in a typical stereo situation?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/377/how-do-binaural-recordings-sound-in-a-typical-stereo-situation)

Comment: @Utopia, +1 for the good links.